# Ubuntu 18.04 no tweak tool

Tags: apt, gnome, gnome-tweak-tool

I am trying to install myself the gnome tweak tool but it is never found!

Thanks for any help :)

Console:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gnome-tweak-tool is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gnome-tweak-tool' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Also Console:Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gnome-tweaks

Comment: have you done `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and then try `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`

Comment: @PRATAP trying now

Comment: @PRATAP I highly thank you, it worked .... not entirely used to this environment yet :)

Comment: Alternatively, you can install the tweak tool and many other good app via Ubuntu Store. Love the store, cheers.

Comment: @BernardWei didn't find it in there, but maybe I'm just blind

Comment: @DaedraEYE That's strange, how about typing "gnome tweaks" in the store, it should find it.

Comment: @BernardWei when I was searching for "tweak" in the ubuntu software store I got 2 completely random programs and nothing else

Comment: @DaedraEYE I posted a screenshot from my search in an answer as I can't post it here. It's weird that you get something so different but this is probably off topic and for another question altogether. May be you have not included some respositories.

Comment: Could you please post an answer based upon PRTAP's comments that helped you solve the problem?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix posted the answer below ^^

Comment: This answer from @Dylan helped me as well: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190232/gnome-tweak-tool-not-found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since @WinEunuuchs2Unix asked, here's the answer based on @PRATAP help:

```
sudo apt update;
sudo apt upgrade -y;
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks;
```

The upgrade part is very important because otherwise the changes from update won't get installed.

Answer (score 11):

That's because Ubuntu 18.04 ships by default with GNOME 3.28, in which they renamed the `gnome-tweak-tool` to `gnome-tweaks`. And in the Activities Overview can be found by searching for **Tweaks**.

If it's not installed then you should be able to install it with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks
```

This is due to Canonical packaging it up like this in order not to confuse users too much with the naming change.

Comment: you can actually search for both and get the same result

Comment: That's because Ubuntu is being nice to you. You won't get that sort of treatment on Arch or Fedora. Or one that delivers a pure  GNOME experience that is.

Comment: that may be right, but my current experience is only windows and ubuntu 18.04 dsktp

Comment: I am using an 16.04 and I had the reverse problem beacuse these day's people are talking about it the other way around so thank you for clarifying. Your answer was my question

Answer (score 0):

Installing Gnome Tweaks from Ubuntu Store; from the store, search for `tweaks`. See attached screenshot.

[image: Ubuntu Store]

Comment: I only have the first two in your list